# reversing a singly linked list by recursion

Tags: java, recursion, singly-linked-list

This is the code for reversing a singly linked list by recursion:

```
public static LinkedListNode reverse_recursive(
      LinkedListNode head) {

    if (head == null || 
        head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    LinkedListNode reversed_list = 
      reverse_recursive(head.next);

    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    return reversed_list;
  }
```

I know recursion is not the best way to solve this problem, but I can't figure out the what the code "head.next.next=head" is doing. I'm confused, please help me clear my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
head.next.next = head
```

is assigning the current node (head) as the link of the node that was last visited by the recursion.

The recursion will begin from the last node in the list and will end on the first node.

Assuming you have the linked list  `A --> B --> C --> D --> NULL`

It will start reversing the above-mentioned list from `node D` and since node D's `next` is `null`, the recursion will immediately move to the next node, `node C`

What will happen is it's going to take head (which is now `node C`), and assign as `node D`'s `next`

This will happen until there are no more nodes left to traverse

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
head --> A
         .next --> B
                   .next --> C
```

So, in the above example `head.next` references the node B, and `head.next.next` referenced the node C.

```
head.next.next = something
```

is thus the equivalent of

```
nodeB.next = something
```

In your code, `something` is `head`. And `head` references the node A. So it assigns a new value to the next node of the node B, and this new value if the node A:

```
head --> A <---------------
         .next --> B      |
                   .next --
```

The following instruction is

```
head.next = null, which thus leads to

head --> A <---------------
                   B      |
                   .next --
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedListNode reverse_recursive(LinkedListNode head) {
if (head == null || head.next == null) {
    return head;
}
```

If the node(in our case head) equals to null or the next node equals to null
(meaning that there is only one node) then return that one node because you can't reverse a null reference or a list with only one node(basically it's already reversed). This is the base case for the recursive solution.

```
LinkedListNode reversed_list = reverse_recursive(head.next);
```

We send the next node into the recursive function e.g. if our list has three nodes 1->2->3 then we would be sending the second node into reverse_recursive function. The function would return 3->2 and reversed_list would point to node 3. And now we need to connect node 1 to the reversed list 3->2.

```
head.next.next = head;
```

head.next (node 2) will point to (head.next.next) node 1 (head).

```
head.next = null;
```

Since node 1 is the last node it should point to null, meaning that there are no more nodes.

```
return reversed_list;
```

And now we only need to return the correct reference (the first node of the reversed list).